# How to merge two stream and sort them in zio streams

Tags: scala, zio, zio-streams

Like akka-stream's [mergeSorted](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Source-or-Flow/mergeSorted.html).
It's very useful when process history data and keep the time order.

What's the replacement in zio-streams?